How can I use streamer.bot api in an iobroker javascript?
I want to connect to the streamer.bot websocket client using the official streamer.bot client: https://streamerbot.github.io/client/get-started/installation via my iobroker javascript instance in an separate script.
I already figured out, that I have to add the npm source "@streamerbot/client" to my javascript instance:

I also added a streamer bot websocket server for my used ip address seperatly:

Firewall is open.
But the problem is, that I'm not able to construct an appropriate instance with my code:


let sbServerAddress = '192.168.0.38';
let sbServerPort = '9090';
const StreamerbotClient = require('@streamerbot/client');

const client = new StreamerbotClient({
    host: sbServerAddress,
    port: sbServerPort,
    endpoint: '/'
});



I'm always getting the error message: javascript.0 (19364) script.js.streaming.Streamer_bot: TypeError: StreamerbotClient is not a constructor
I tried to make a direct WebSocket connection, which is connecting. I really want to use the specialized client. What are I'm missing?
This is my WebSocket code:


const WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

function connectws() {
    const ws = new WebSocketClient();

    // Reconnect
    ws.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Websocket closed');
        setTimeout(connectws, 5000);
    });

    ws.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
        console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
    });

    ws.on('connect', function (connection) {
        console.log('Websocket opened');
    });

    ws.connect("ws://" + sbServerAddress + ":" + sbServerPort + "/", null);
}

connectws();




I know this is a bit old, but here for those that find this question from google. The problem was when importing the library, you had to call it like this:
const StreamerbotClient = require('@streamerbot/client').StreamerbotClient;

I also called it like the docs said, but since I got the error, I had to check how it was being exported, and it's exporting not only StreamerbotClient but also DefaultStreamerbotClientOptions they should change the docs so beginners don't get confused.

That's a good point. I solved the problem by my own in the past, but forgot to update this post.
